# How to highlight contents in an Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have setup an Array so I can check the content of a worksheet.  Where I find inconsistences I want to highlight them.  I "tried" to use `.Interior.colourindex` but this doesn't work.  I researched it and this function changes the interior colour of the cell, as I'm in an Array I can't do this.  Below is my code with the `.interior.colourindex` included in it (clearly not working).  I would be grateful if someone could tell me an alternative way to highlight these differences please?

Code:

```
Sub AcidMap()

gFrow = 1
gLastrow = FindLastRow(gcsAmort)
gLastcolumn = FindLastCol(gcsAmort)

gVmyArray = Sheets(gcsAmort).Range(Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(1, gLastcolumn))
gVAmortArray = Sheets(gcsAmort).Range(Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(gLastrow, gLastcolumn))

For x = LBound(gVAmortArray) To UBound(gVAmortArray)

    If gVAmortArray(x, 1) <> "ID" Then

            If gVAmortArray(x, 1) = gVAmortArray(x - 1, 1) Then


            For y = 1 To 3

                If y <> 1 Then

                    If gVAmortArray(x, y) <> gVAmortArray(x - 1, y) Then

                        gVAmortArray(x, y).Interior.ColorIndex = 5


                    End If

                End If

             Next y

        End If

    End If

Next x

Sheets(gcsAmort).Range(Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(gLastrow, gLastcolumn)) = gVAmortArray

MsgBox "Macro Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried conditional formatting using a formula?

Comment: An array of values is stored as values in memory and not tied to the cells from which the values came.  Since it is just the values there is no associated format.

Comment: Thanks David - I don't want to use conditional formatting (CF)as the workbook is massive and CF will murder the performance.   Scott - Thanks for your input.  That feedback is in line with what I read up - I need to find an alternative way to highlighting these cells.  Once again thanks for input.

Comment: You can use Offset: `Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(1, 1).Offset(x-1, y-1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5`

Comment: Scott - That works - Thank you so much....!!!!!!!!!  Can you put that through as an answer so I can give you the credit for it.  Thanks once again.  Ciaran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to highlight the array just highlight the cell that  corresponds to the value in the array.

Instead of:

```
gVAmortArray(x, y).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

Use offset anchored to the first cell and using you x and y:

```
Sheets(gcsAmort).Cells(1, 1).Offset(x-1, y-1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

And since you are not doing anything to the values in the array there is no need to paste the same values back, so you can remove that line to save a step.

Comment: Once again - Thanks Scott for you input.